# How do i pass/use a method from form1 in a new class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In form1 i have a method i changed it to public:

```
public bool ComparingImages(Bitmap File1)
        {
        }
```

Then i created a new class and did:

```
private Form f1;

        public SimulateDownloads(Form form1)
        {
            f1 = form1;
        }
```

Then in the new class bottom in another method i did:

```
bool downloaded = f1.ComparingImages(test);
```

But f1 does not contain ComparingImages

I tried also to add to form1 constructor:

```
private SimulateDownloads simdownloads;

        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            simdownloads = new SimulateDownloads(this);
```

But i don't want to run the program first i want to be able now without running the program to call the method ComparingImages in form1 to call it from the new class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is that your `SimulateDownloads` method is taking in an object of type `Form` instead of type `Form1`. Remember, you put the public method on a class called `Form1`, you did not add it to the base `Form` class!

Try this:

```
// (This is in your other form, not Form1)
private Form1 f1;

public SimulateDownloads(Form1 form1)
{
    f1 = form1;
}
```

Then you should be able to do this in your other form:

```
bool downloaded = f1.ComparingImages(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `ComparingImages` shouldn't be in the form1 at all. Create a new class `Utils` or similar and put `ComparingImages` in that class. Then you can use

```
bool downloaded = new Utils().ComparingImages(test); //or Utils.ComparingImages(test); if you make it static
```

from both `SimulateDownloads` and `form1`